# How to estimate proportions when there are "irrelevant" observations?

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion

For example, if a supermarket only sells apples and oranges and would like to know the proportion of apple sales vs. the total. I have collected n data points, each data point has (# of apple, # of oranges). For *p* out of these *n* data points, both of the counts are 0. When I try to provide CI for the estimated proportions, should I treat my sample size to be *n* or *n-p*?

I know that the proportion estimation will remain the same no matter what, but the CI will be smaller if I use *n*. How should I deal with those (0,0) observations?

Comment: A better way of doing it might be to sum up all the apple sales and sum up all the orange sales, then calculate the ratio on the basis of the totals.  Then you don't end up averaging (1,0) data points with (30,30) data points as though they were somehow equivalent in terms of their information content, and you don't have to worry about (0,0) data points either.

Comment: yes, that is what I'm doing. But in order to calculate the standard error, should I use the total # of observations including the (0,0) data points? Since that would decrease my CI interval, I'm confused about why would (0,0) observations make my estimation more confident?

Comment: No, you would use the total number of observations $N$ (= apples + oranges), not the total number of data points $n$.  The formula for the s.e. of the estimated proportion $\hat{p}$ is $\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/N}$.